# Is there a method to find the order of a lift of an element of order 2 to the Schur cover?

Tags: finite-groups, schur-multipliers

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian simple group, $M.G$ the Schur covering group of $G$. Is there a method to find the order of a preimage of an element of order 2 in the natural homomorphism $\pi: M.G\rightarrow G$?

We can find the result using the 'Atlas of finite groups' for some finite simple groups, but is there a general method?

Comment: See this MO question and comments there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130988/why-are-schur-multipliers-of-finite-simple-groups-so-small

Comment: Thank you very much!